# Change app path of a Laravel 5.5.46 application

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I designed a Laravel application using the path suggested in the documentation:

```
folders:
- map: /var/www/virusapp
  to: /home/vagrant/code
```

Everything worked fine. Now I'm developing more applications so I changed my folders data to:

```
folders:
    - map: /var/www/virusapp
      to: /home/vagrant/virusapp
    - map: /var/www/pinetus
      to: /home/vagrant/pinetus
```

The initial virusapp cannot find the views anymore even though I haven't changed anything except my folders path. Please help me.